# Cannot Select TableViewCell when Search Bar is active - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, tableview, searchbar

I have a search bar that is connected to a table view. It works exactly as I want when the search bar is not active but cell selection is disabled when the search bar is active. I've debugged it and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not even being called when I select a row when search is active. What could be causing this?

Here's the relevant code:

```
class FabricsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        myTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if searching {
            searching = false
            searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()
            FirebaseClient.sharedInstance.joinFabric(uid: self.appDelegate.uid!, fabricKey: allFabrics[indexPath.row].key)
            updateFabricList()
        } else {
             appDelegate.selectedFabricKey = joinedFabrics[indexPath.row].key
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "fabricSelected", sender: self)
        }
        myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        if let allFabrics = allFabrics {
            filteredFabrics = allFabrics.filter { fabric in
                return (fabric.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
            myTableView.reloadData()
            myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
        }
    }

}

extension FabricsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your issue ? tell clearly

Comment: myTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false) remove this line and check it.

Comment: I can select rows when the search bar is inactive. However, when the search bar becomes active and a filtered list is displayed in the table view, I can no longer select the cells. The problem can't be deselectRow because didSelectRowAt indexPath isn't even called when the search bar is active. Is it something to do with the delegate of the table view?

Comment: updateFabricList() show your this method

Comment: Try setting `searchController. searchBar.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Hi @Adam Zarn did you got answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the text for your method name.
   Make sure that you are using method name as below:

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

2. You have set the delegate of searchBar to self. Are you activating any tap gestures when search becomes active? This tap gesture can interrupt your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing same issue, according Apple's documentation you should have following code for add searchController:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   navigationItem.searchController = searchController
} else {
    self.yourTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```